# unable to start activity:StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -2

Tags: android, substring, indexoutofboundsexception, string-function

I am retriving data from table and display it in textview , i  have break the string using breakString() method but in last two data that are starcast and director , its showing StringIndexOutOfBoundsException...
as i have debug the app data are still inside the string but the debugging stops when it reaches to starcast...

breakString() method

```
   public void breakString(String str)
    {
        name=str.substring(1,str.indexOf(","));
        str= str.substring( name.length()+2, str.length(  ) );

        genre=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));
        str= str.substring( genre.length()+1, str.length(  ) );

        year=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));
        str= str.substring( year.length()+1, str.length(  ) );

        duration=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));
        str= str.substring( duration.length()+1, str.length(  ) );

        String str1 = str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));
        rating=Double.valueOf(str1);

        str = str.substring( str1.length()+1, str.length() );
        review = str.substring(0,str.indexOf( "," ));
        str=str.substring(review.length()+1,str.indexOf(","));

        starcast = str.substring( 0, str.indexOf( "," ));
        str = str.substring( starcast.length()+1, str.indexOf(","));
       // str = str1.substring( starcast.length()+1, str.length()-1 );

        director = str;

    }
```

debug mode image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov6Mw.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8jca.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ts5j.jpg)

after this the debugging stops and nothing is being generted.

Comment: You never showed us what this string is.  Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: understand the string pattern first then you can easily break strings using Regex.

Comment: string is shown in debug image

Comment: string is [Movie name,biography,2018,250,5,i have started this from the last few months,ron,tim]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Your problem is in the following line:

```
 str=str.substring(review.length()+1,str.indexOf(",")) //Original
 str=str.substring(review.length()+1,str.length()); // Should be
```

***The program crashed since the length of review is 45 and the indexOf the comma is 44.***

Comment: @YashDadhaniya - The end of your string, after Tim, does not have a comma and you want to retrieve it. I can see "Ron, Tim".

Comment: string is [Movie name,biography,2018,250,5,i have started this from the last few months,ron,tim]

Comment: yes but i want to retrive ron in str variable that is not happning

Comment: and then tim ... so for tim i have written director = str

Comment: debugger is not even reaching last three lines even if i am having values [ron, tim ] inside str variable

Answer (score 0):

After simple Unit test:

```
str = str.substring(review.length()+1, str.length());
...
str = str.substring(starcast.length()+1, str.length());
```

However, I strongly recommend [StringTokenizer](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/StringTokenizer).